# Ember's registerBoundHelper and handlebar blocks

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

So I have taken the 'is' helper block from [here](https://github.com/danharper/Handlebars-Helpers) and modified it so that it register's it's helper through Ember using registerBoundHelper

The reason I did that is because I basically need a handlebars based 'switch' statement.  The end result in my handlebars is as follows:

```
{{#is MyProperty 1}}
    ...Do something here...
{{/is}}
{{#is MyProperty 2}}
    ...Do something here...
{{/is}}
{{#is MyProperty 3}}
    ...Do something here...
{{/is}}
{{#is MyProperty 4}}
    ...Do something here...
{{/is}}
```

The is statement just does a simple comparison between 'MyProperty's *value* and a constant.

If I don't use 'registerBoundHelper' MyProperty gets passed through as the string literal 'MyProperty' and not it's *value*.

Now:  **This logic appears to work when I actually run it**

The issue is that Ember throws the following error:

```
registerBoundHelper-generated helpers do not support use with Handlebars blocks.
```

Should I ignore this error and just continue on because it does appear to be working?  Or should I try to rework the logic to not use a block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't ignore it because it isn't supported, if `MyProperty` were to change after the render has occurred it will break.

Conditional helpers aren't supported (to many of our demise) in ember handlebars.  The reason being is the core team wants this logic as a computed property instead of logic in the template.

IE

#### Controller

```
App.IndexController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  isPropertyOne: Em.computed.equal('myProperty', '1')
});
```

#### Template

```
  {{#if isPropertyOne}}
    any template stuff
    {{render 'something'}}
    {{someValue}}
  {{/if}}
```

Comment: I thought this were the case...But how would I replicate handlebar templating in a computed property?  I.E.  If inside of my conditional block I have another template

Comment: nevermind, went with a view tied to a computed property...probably the best way to handle this anyways so the logic is not run through a template